# mailto links in mailings go to blank page

Tags: civimail, tracked-links

anyone seeing an issue where mailto links in mailings don't open a new email dialog when clicked on, but instead open a blank page? I'm assuming this is due to the URL tracking not converting it correctly back to a mailto link.

Click-through tracking is turned on for these mailings

The HTML code is pretty standard, e.g. info@example.com

If I use plain text (i.e. without the  tag), most email clients convert it into the correct mailto link so that could technically be a work-around, but the problem is the mailing clients apply the local default styling for this link - not a huge deal, but still a nuisance.

I can't recall if this used to work correctly before

We're using CiviCRM 5.41.0 with Joomla 3.10.1

Anything I can check on? Or is this a bug? Thank you!

Comment: Are you specifically formatting it as a 'mailto' link or relying on some automatic handling to recognise an address and handle it as a link?

Comment: sorry, yes, <a href="mailto:info@example.com" ... >info@example.com</a> ... however, all of a sudden, today it works again (I did not upgrade CiviCRM, or make any other changes ... go figure). I'll observe this for a few more days, and will resolve the question if I can't repro the issue again

Comment: the issue self-resolved ... not sure what caused the temporary (2-3-week) lapse; sorry about the false alarm