# Do folks experience issues with hyperlinking emails in mosaico emails?

Tags: civimail, mosaico

WP, Civi 5.69.5

Scenario: add language to mosaico email body that "Email Bob if you have any questions" hyperlink Email Bob to bob@example.org - because its a trackable link - instead of just opening a new message, it will open the browser which will open the link, which will open the default email program - which hopefully the user has set.

This is typically fine but for some users - especially outlook users that have microsoft safelinks - they are getting weird behavior. It opens the browser and sometimes just loads a blank page which then, upon refresh, will open the email link.

I wonder if there is a way to exclude mailto: hyperlinks from being tracked - in the meantime or if folks have best practices around email links in bulk emails.

Comment: Duplicate of https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/q/40367/12?

Comment: might be - that user seems to think it self-resolved itself - but this is something we have gotten user feedback on for a while. For the record - seems to be fine for most recipients, only those that have not set their default email application or outlook/exchange users with safelinks.